# Problems with Linux SVN server

Tags: linux, svn, tortoisesvn

I have an SVN server running in my Redmine server.  I have run the following to make sure I am up-to-date:

```
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade
```

I am able to connect, update, commit, etc but I am having problems getting history/log from my svn server from either TortoiseSVN or a linux svn client.

My SVN Server (running on Debian) version is:

```
svnserv, version 1.6.17 (r1128011)
   compiled Aug 10 2015, 05:02:48

Copyright (C) 2000-2009 CollabNet.
```

My TortoiseSVN Client (running on Windows 10) is:

```
TortoiseSVN 1.9.1, Build 26747 - 64 Bit , 2015/08/31 20:16:00
Subversion 1.9.1, -release
apr 1.5.2
apr-util 1.5.4
serf 1.3.8
OpenSSL 1.0.2d 9 Jul 2015
zlib 1.2.8
SQLite 3.8.11.1
```

My Linux svn client (running on Ubuntu) is:

```
svn, version 1.8.8 (r1568071)
   compiled Aug 20 2015, 12:51:30 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
```

TortoiseSVN gives me this error:

```
There has been a problem contacting the server.
Do you want to see the cached data instead?

Please understand that the cached data may be outdated,
incomplete or even misleading due to the incomplete history data.
```

Linux gives me this error:

```
svn: E220001: Item is not readable
```

Here is my svn log (I did not see any errors):

```
7397 2015-09-13T19:26:46.156052Z 192.168.1.1 - thompco open 2 cap=(edit-pipeline svndiff1 absent-entries depth mergeinfo log-revprops) /garageMonitor/scripts/update.sh SVN/1.8.8%20(x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) -
7397 2015-09-13T19:26:46.174812Z 192.168.1.1 - thompco reparent /garageMonitor/scripts/update.sh
7397 2015-09-13T19:26:46.187860Z 192.168.1.1 - thompco log (/garageMonitor/scripts/update.sh) r61:0 revprops=(svn:author svn:date svn:log)
7398 2015-09-13T19:27:12.196359Z 192.168.1.1 - thompco open 2 cap=(edit-pipeline svndiff1 absent-entries depth mergeinfo log-revprops) /garageMonitor/scripts/update.sh SVN/1.9.1%20(x64-microsoft-windows) TortoiseSVN-1.9.1.26747
7398 2015-09-13T19:27:12.224528Z 192.168.1.1 - thompco get-latest-rev
7399 2015-09-13T19:27:12.236982Z 192.168.1.1 - thompco open 2 cap=(edit-pipeline svndiff1 absent-entries depth mergeinfo log-revprops) /garageMonitor/scripts/update.sh SVN/1.9.1%20(x64-microsoft-windows) TortoiseSVN-1.9.1.26747
7399 2015-09-13T19:27:12.240851Z 192.168.1.1 - thompco reparent /garageMonitor/scripts/update.sh
7399 2015-09-13T19:27:12.243852Z 192.168.1.1 - thompco log (/garageMonitor/scripts/update.sh) r61:0 limit=100 discover-changed-paths revprops=(svn:log svn:date svn:author)
7400 2015-09-13T19:27:13.498247Z 192.168.1.1 - thompco open 2 cap=(edit-pipeline svndiff1 absent-entries depth mergeinfo log-revprops) /garageMonitor/scripts/update.sh SVN/1.9.1%20(x64-microsoft-windows) TortoiseSVN-1.9.1.26747
7400 2015-09-13T19:27:13.505382Z 192.168.1.1 - thompco reparent /garageMonitor/scripts/update.sh
7400 2015-09-13T19:27:13.518023Z 192.168.1.1 jordan thompco stat /garageMonitor/scripts/update.sh@61
```

Any suggestions would be most welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem... 
in the 
`/srv/repos/svn/[repo name]/conf/authz` file I found this:

`[/]
my_username = rw`

it should read:
`[/]
my_username = r`

Answer (score 0):

I had a same issue with my subversion setup, after lot of search I got a solutions as below

**Solution 1**

You need to add below lines in authz file.

```
[/]
* = r
```

**Solution 2**

Make sure you have below lines in your svnserve.conf

```
anon-access = none
auth-access = write
```

I Hope it will solve your issues, Best Luck !